# Ayuda con error en Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++

Buenas tardes, alguien podria ayudarme con el siguiente problema en mi codigo c++.

```
1>  Generating Code...
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\string.h(54): warning RC4011: identifier truncated to '_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDA'
1>  
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\string.h(76): warning RC4011: identifier truncated to '_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_SECURE'
1> 
1>  Info.vcxproj -> C:\Users\gramt\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Info\Debug\Info.exe

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\string.h(54): warning RC4011: identifier truncated to '_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDA'
```

Este error corresponde a este código dentro de la cabecera `string.h`

El codigo:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus) && _CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES_MEMORY
extern "C++"
{
 #ifndef _CRT_ENABLE_IF_DEFINED
  #define _CRT_ENABLE_IF_DEFINED
    template<bool _Enable, typename _Ty>
    struct _CrtEnableIf;

    template<typename _Ty>
    struct _CrtEnableIf<true, _Ty>
    {
        typedef _Ty _Type;
    };
 #endif
    template <size_t _Size, typename _DstType>
    inline
    typename _CrtEnableIf<(_Size > 1), void *>::_Type __cdecl memcpy(_DstType (&_Dst)[_Size], _In_opt_bytecount_(_SrcSize) const void *_Src, _In_ size_t _SrcSize) _CRT_SECURE_CPP_NOTHROW
    {
        return memcpy_s(_Dst, _Size * sizeof(_DstType), _Src, _SrcSize) == 0 ? _Dst : 0;
    }
}
#endif
```

Otro error:

```
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\string.h(76): warning RC4011: identifier truncated to '_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_SECURE'
```

Este error corresponde a este código dentro de la cabecera `string.h`

El codigo:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus) && _CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_SECURE_NAMES_MEMORY
extern "C++"
{
    template <size_t _Size, typename _DstType>
    inline
    errno_t __CRTDECL memcpy_s(_DstType (&_Dst)[_Size], _In_opt_bytecount_(_SrcSize) const void * _Src, _In_ rsize_t _SrcSize) _CRT_SECURE_CPP_NOTHROW </P>
    {
        return memcpy_s(_Dst, _Size * sizeof(_DstType), _Src, _SrcSize);
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Prueba compilar con `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`, agregalo en el pragma o en el compilador...

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio bastante bien, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar no son mensajes de error sino de advertencia (no es lo mismo *error* que *warning* aunque haya que prestar atención a ambos tipos de mensajes).

Después, si echamos un vistazo a la [documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/0s9de8h2.aspx) de Microsoft sobre el error:

> identificador truncado en 'identifier'
>
> Un identificador era demasiado largo y se ha truncado en el nombre que aparece en la advertencia.

Así pues parece que el origen del problema es exactamente el mismo que el que te está mostrando el compilador:

```
warning RC4011: identifier truncated to '_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDA'
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Una solución pasa entonces por reducir la longitud del identificador para evitar el mensaje de advertencia.

Por cierto, te muestra una advertencia en vez de un error porque el código puede compilar... la advertencia está presente porque al truncar los identificadores puede suceder que dos diferentes acaben coincidiendo.

Visto lo visto el tamaño de los identificadores en VS2010 está limitado a 31 caracteres (32 si añadimos el finalizador de cadena).

Como nota final. No se qué pretendes con eso de `extern C++` pero no sirve para **absolutamente nada**. Bueno, vamos a matizarlo un poco.

`extern C` sirve para permitir un enlazado a la usanza de C, lo que permite crear código compatible con C y con C++ (una interfaz de unión). En cambio `extern C++` permite, en el caso de trabajar con C, indicar que ahí se encuentra código C++... lo que permite que el compilador ignore esa instrucción y se quede tan contento... dudo muy mucho que estés mezclando compiladores en tu caso así que es mejor que dejes de usar esa característica, lo que te permitirá limpiar un poco el código.

Comment: Tiene razon conforme a las advertencias, pero la cabecera string.h es un archivo de inclusion dentro de Visual C++ 2010; queda claro que es un identificador truncado y tomare las medidas conforme a lo que comenta; muchas gracias

Comment: @jose_luis_rangel entiende que yo desconozco el origen de ese archivo... posiblemente no sea el específico para la versión de VS que estás usando...